# COM Add-in: Resolve the error DisconnectedContext in WinWord.exe

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio, com

I built an add-on to Microsoft Word. When the user clicks a button, it runs a number of processes that export a list of Microsoft Word documents to Filtered HTML. This works fine.

Where the code falls down is in processing large amounts of files. After the file conversions are done and I call the next function, the app crashes and I get this information from Visual Studio:

> Managed Debugging Assistant 'DisconnectedContext' has detected a problem in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE'.
>
> Additional information: Transition into COM context 0x56255b88 for
>   this RuntimeCallableWrapper failed with the following error: System
>   call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010100
>   (RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED)). This is typically because the COM context
>   0x56255b88 where this RuntimeCallableWrapper was created has been
>   disconnected or it is busy doing something else. Releasing the
>   interfaces from the current COM context (COM context 0x56255cb0). This
>   may cause corruption or data loss. To avoid this problem, please
>   ensure that all COM contexts/apartments/threads stay alive and are
>   available for context transition, until the application is completely
>   done with the RuntimeCallableWrappers that represents COM components
>   that live inside them.

After some testing, I realized that if I simply remove all the code after the file conversions, there are no problems. To resolve this, I place the remainder of my code in yet another button.

The problem is I don't want to give the user two buttons. After reading various other threads, it sounds like my code has a memory or threading issue. The answers I am reading do not help me truly understand what to do next.

I feel like this is what I want to do:

1- Run conversion.
2- Close thread/cleanup memory issue from conversion.
3- Continue running code.

Unfortunately, I really don't know how to do #2 or if it is even possible. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> or it is busy doing something else

The managed debugging assistant diagnostic you got is pretty gobbledygooky but that's the part of the message that accurately describes the real problem.  You have a *firehose* problem, the 3rd most common issue associated with threading.  The mishap is hard to diagnose because this goes wrong inside the Word plumbing and not your code.

Trying not to commit the same gobbledygook sin myself, what goes wrong is that the interop calls you make into the Office program are queued, waiting for their turn to get executed.  The underlying "system call" that the error code hints at is PostMessage().  Wherever there is a queue, there is a risk that the queue gets too large.  Happens when the producer (your program) is adding items too the queue far faster than the consumer (the Office program) removes them.  The firehose problem.  Unless the producer slows down, the queue will grow without bounds and *something* is going to fail if it is allowed to grow endlessly, at a minimum the process runs out of memory.

It is not allowed to get close to that problem.  The underlying queue that PostMessage() uses is protected by the OS.  Windows fails the call when the queue already contains 10,000 messages.  That's a fatal error that RPC does not know how to recover from, or rather should not try to recover from.  Something is amiss and it isn't pretty.  It returns an error code to your program to tell you about it.  That's RPC_E_SYS_CALL_FAILED.  Nothing much better happens in your program, the CLR doesn't know how to recover from it either, nor does your code.  So the show is over, the interop call you made got lost and was not executed by Word.

Finding a completely reliable workaround for this awkward problem is not that straight-forward.  Beware that this can happen on *any* interop call, so catching the exception and trying again is pretty drastically unpractical.  But do keep in mind that the Q+D fix is very simple.  The plain problem is that your program is running too fast, slowing it down with a Thread.Sleep() or Task.Delay() call is quite crude but will always fix the issue.  Well, assuming you delay enough.

I think, but don't know for a fact because nobody ever posts repro code, that this issue is also associated with using a console mode app or a worker thread in your program.  If it is a console mode app then try applying the [STAThread] attribute to your Main() method.  If it is a worker thread then call Thread.SetApartmentState() before starting the thread, but beware it is very important to also create the Application interface on that worker thread.  Not otherwise a workaround for an add-in.

If neither of those workarounds is effective or too unpractical then consider that you can automagically slow your program down, and ensure the queue is emptied, by occasionally reading something back from the Office program.  Something silly, any property getter call will do.  Necessarily you can't get the property value until the Office program catches up.  That can *still* fail, there is also a 60 second time-out on the interop call.  But that's something you can fix, you can call CoRegisterMessageFilter() in your program to install a callback that runs when the timeout trips.  Very gobbledygooky as well, but the cut-and-paste code is [readily available](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andreww/2008/11/19/implementing-imessagefilter-in-an-office-add-in/).

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed response. This is the first answer that really gave me a full understanding of what was going on. While I see there are a lot of potential options for me, using `Thread.Sleep(3000)` before processing each new file seems to have done the trick. For now, I will see how that goes and will create a value the user can modify if they have a problem. My test cases were designed to hit the upper limits of my product's capabilities so I am hopeful this does not prove to be a widespread problem. If it is, I will tackle some of the more complex examples you shared.